# Batch files: reboot after pause?

Tags: batch-file, crash, restart, reboot

I'm looking for a solution to reboot the system if the batch crashes and the "pause" command line (Press any key to continue...) gets triggered.

Is it possible to scan for the line (Press any key to continue) and force a complete reboot? Will something like this work?

```
@echo off
TIMEOUT /T 20
AppWhichLikesToCrash.exe
pause
:loop
echo Press any key to continue...
shutdown -t 0 -r -f
goto loop
```

I found solutions but they are turning the batch to a service, I don't want to do this.

Comment: What is keeping you from changing the "pause" command to your shutdown command?

Comment: You might be able to redirect the output of the command to a file and then the separate script could read the file and `find` "Press any key to continue...".

Comment: lol is this possible? you mean leave out the loop and replace pause with "shutdown -t 0 -r -f"? I went the way to check with tasklist /im and restart if task is gone. This is for a 24/7 running app, will report back if it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

When your application really crashes (=not existent any more), then the following should work:

```
@echo off
TIMEOUT /T 20
AppWhichLikesToCrash.exe
:loop
timeout /t 10
tasklist /im "AppWhichLikesToCrash.exe" && goto :loop
shutdown -t 0 -r -f
```

Comment: thanks for your help. With "crash" I mean the process gets paused but the command prompt is still open. Pause gets triggered, "Press any key to continue" shows up and it doesn't run anymore. In this case I need the batch to restart and the simplest way is to force a reboot (batch is in windows startup folder). Your solution can work I think, I have to check if the .exe is really crashing. thanks!

Comment: so if I understand correctly, the application runs and only when it "crashes", your batch file reaches the `pause` command?

Comment: Yes, correct. I have added your advice with tasklist and if it isn't there anymore force a reboot like recommended

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered Choice with Timeout switch over pause?
IE if the app has a habit of crashing on startup or withing a short timeframe, 
Set choice with a short delay with a default that sends you back to the point in the program you wish to restart from
If the App starts or runs sussecfully beyond a certain point, you can proceed with the other choice option/s
You can throw in alternative options as desired to terminate the app or display options with /M "option here"

```
CHOICE /T 30 /C cr /N /D r >nul
IF ERRORLEVEL ==2 GOTO restart
IF ERRORLEVEL ==1 GOTO continue
```